# Таблица с соблюдением всех 3 условий

Tags: sql

Найти всех, кто играл на всех 3 аренах из кода, почему-то через and не работает

```
select distinct pi.player_id, pi.firstName, pi.lastName, g.venue
from player_info pi
join game_goalie_stats ggs on ggs.player_id = pi.player_id
join game g on g.game_id = ggs.game_id
where year( g.date_time_GMT ) = 2018 and 
    exists(select * from player_info where
    g.venue = 'TD Garden') or 
    exists (select * from player_info where g.venue = 'Honda Center' ) or 
    exists (select * from player_info where g.venue = 'Amalie Arena' )


    order by firstName
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `.. HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT арена) = 3`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как правильно сказали в комментариях, можно через having count(distinct g.venue) = 3

```
select pi.player_id, pi.firstName, pi.lastName
from player_info pi
join game_goalie_stats ggs on ggs.player_id = pi.player_id
join game g on g.game_id = ggs.game_id
where year( g.date_time_GMT ) = 2018
group by pi.player_id, pi.firstName, pi.lastName
having count(distinct g.venue) = 3
```

В данном случае этого достаточно. Однако distinct - это сортировка, т.е. O(N*Ln(N)), однако можно обойтись максимумами, иногда бывает значительно быстрее работает, там сложность уже O(N). Выглядит примерно так:

```
group by pi.player_id, pi.firstName, pi.lastName
having 3 =
  max(case when g.venue = 'TD Garden' then 1 else 0 end) + 
  max(case when g.venue = 'Honda Center' then 1 else 0 end) + 
  max(case when g.venue = 'Amalie Arena' then 1 else 0 end)
```